# Deploying to Nexus using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

We currently have Jenkins jobs to build the infrastructure for our suite of products. This job invokes ant to package various jar files under our build directory.

i.e.

```
build
     lib
         common.jar
         ldap.jar
         filesplit.jar
         rmiservice.jar
         .
         .
         .
```

My question is what is the best way to implement this so that we can deploy the built jar files to Nexus in bulk? Or is the best/only way to do this is to have a pom.xml file with each artifact specified with a build.gradle or Jenkins pipeline?

Thoughts? Best approach? Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: The question is whether you really want to migrate to Maven. This will probably mean that you need to change a lot of things in your build process. Or is this question just about deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Their is apparently an official plugin to deploy to nexus from an ant task.

https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-ant-tasks/tree/master/nexus-staging-ant-tasks

Once your deployment works from command line, automate it with Jenkins. Don't try to multi task you would loose time.

If you consider that deploying to nexus could be an excuse to migrate to a modern build system and replace Ant, go for Gradle

Comment: Or use the most popular build system with the most existing plugins: Maven.

Comment: your point of view JF Meier is so sad :( I understand the debates mac or windows, Emacs or Vim. But there is no possible debate between Ant < Maven < Gradle

Comment: Of course there is. Maven is a very established build system with a clear philosophy and many stable plugins for various purposes. I can really recommend it.

Comment: I have seen people extending maven with groovy code inside pom.xml. It's the most horrific thing ever. Have an exemple here https://github.com/syndesisio/syndesis-extensions/blob/af61fb81c74ce02cc4cd63451eca4620e8718c46/pom.xml#L114-L180 How ppl use maven is often far from its original philosophy

Comment: My view: Follow the Maven philosophy as far as possible. Respect the lifecycle and the expectations. If you need something extra, write a Maven plugin. If you need something that goes against the Maven philosophy, and you think you have some "unique" requirements, you are probably on the wrong track. Of course, legacy environments sometimes require such unique solutions, but then get rid of them as soon as possible. And of course, Maven has shortcomings. But most of the things you perceive as shortcomings are design decisions with some reasons (that you may not see).

Comment: if a dev needs some extra, writing a groovy script inside the pom.xml is simpler than writing a maven plugin. No need for him to understand how to write a plugin, no need to go through the prossess of hosting it on a private repository. Tada you got some extra that you can't debug (without println) nor have code highlight in your pom \o/

Comment: We actually try to _stop_ the devs from doing something "extra", but follow the process. The Maven people write the Maven plugins, the devs use them. If they miss a feature, they talk to us. More often than not, their "missing feature" is just a misunderstanding of the process or will break something else.

Comment: even with the best processes you can't stop the dev  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZnt-0fEiT0

Answer (score 1):

Agree w/ @jf-meier; migrate to [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). It has many benefits, though it can be a heavy lift.

Nevertheless, [aether-ant](https://github.com/eclipse/aether-ant) works well and acts as a good transition phase as well. Documented to [work with Nexus](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/maven-and-other-build-tools/apache-ant-and-eclipse-aether).

We've used it extensively to help teams for years. It uses the same engine that is within maven itself.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at aether-ant as we migrate our projects to Maven

Comment: Did the answer help you along using ant and aether?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment.. I decided to use a combination of Ant and Maven. Since our projects are predominantly built using Ant I kept the stand build the way it was. I added pom files to the necessary build directories to pull down any dependencies needed for the builds. I also have pom files for deployments there after. As for Jenkins our converted our freestyle job into a pipeline to visually see each step of the build.deploy process. Maven did the trick, thanks!